# OWL API - Store a Class to which an Individual belongs rather than printing it

Tags: java, owl-api

`EntitySearcher.getTypes(individual, ontology)` returns a Stream of `OWLClassExpression`.

to print it we do:

```
 EntitySearcher.getTypes(individual, ontology).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Instead i want to store the output in an OWLClass or a Set of OWLClass to deal with it later. How do i do that?

The Stream operations are confusing me.

Sincere regards

Comment: ".collect(Collections.toSet())"  instead of ".forEach(...)"   another way is to learn how java-Stream works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn a stream into a set, there's a utility in OWLAPIStreamUtils::asSet(Stream) - this is just a convenience around the standard Collectors class.

To get OWLClass only, you need to filter the types:

Set classes = OWLAPIStreamUtils.asSet(
                                                 EntitySearcher.getTypes(individual, ontology)
                                                 .filter(OWLClassExpression::isOWLClass));